# How to pause an Brightcove video with autostart parameter immediately after page load?

Tags: javascript, video, dom-events, brightcove, mediaplayback

We are trying to display a video where upon template load, the viewer can initiate different cue points in the video by clicking on different thumbnails. The problem is that this doesn't work unless the video is already playing, and we don't want it to play automatically on page load. Is there a way to have the video start to play on template load and immediately pause? We have tried the `pause()` method within `onTemplateLoaded` and `onTemplateReady` functions with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was banging my head against the wall on this question too. I used a lot of example code from http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/solutions/chaptered-video.html

You should be able to videoPlayer.play() the video somewhere in onTemplateReady and call videoPlayer.pause(true) on onMediaBegin following along with the example code.

This worked for me on the desktop but not for mobile.

Comment: Thanks, Alex, I found the same thing with some help from Brightcove Support. The onMediaBegin event listener was key. I've also found that autostart goes out the window on mobile devices but for the purposes of the site we were building, that was tolerable.